# flex 4 list no selectable false?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, flash-builder, flex-mobile

is there any way to either set a flex 4 list component to selectable "false" or disable/hide its selectioncolor? I've tried to change it designview, but it doesn't allow me change it that way. I've also tried tweaking it via the list component or the scroller/viewport control via as3, but I really can't seem to fin a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list that doesn't have selection, you can quickly change it into `DataGroup`. Sometimes I even prefer using `DataGroup` instead of the `List` and if I need to manage a selection I add the selection state to the items in the **data provider**, thus each item would know whether it is selected. This solution allows me to perform filtering, sorting, reordering on the list and still keep the selected state of the items.

Answer (score 1):

try to put this on

```
ItemRenderer property
autoDrawBackground="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an item renderer for the List, and set the selection color in the item renderer. Here are some examples of this:

[Styling both foreground and background selection color in a Flex list/datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939073/styling-both-foreground-and-background-selection-color-in-a-flex-list-datagrid)